# In VS code, for some reason i cannot run any python file because it writes python instead of py in cmd. is there anyway to fix it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code

in vs code, for some reason, i cannot run any python code because vs code puts in python instead of py in cmd. 
it shows this :

> [Running] python -u "c:\Users..."

but is supposed to show this :

> [Running] py -u "c:\Users\

i have tried searching online how to fix it, the error message:

**'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file.**

but comes up with useless answers

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((360,360))
```

what is outputted:

> [Running] python -u "c:\Users..."

as you can see it inputs the wrong command and i have no idea how to fix it.
The expected input:

> [Running] py -u "c:\Users..."

Comment: Make an alias for py with the name python

Comment: `py` is just a launcher the runs `python` and using it isn't a requirement. It looks like you don't have the python interpreter installed.

Answer (score 1):

Well you can change the interpreter that Code uses by pressing `Ctrl+Shift+P` and then searching for `Python: Select Interpreter`, this should help when it comes to running the code in the IDE. If that doesn't work you could just try and use the built in terminal in Code to run the code manually with the `py` command.

Comment: if VSC has found 1 or more Python interpreters it will show in the bottom left status bar. If you click on this you can switch the current Python interpreter.

Answer (score 0):

In VSCODE debug mode I have launch json as follows and then i can easily debug the code with breakpoints

```
{
// Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
// Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
// For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [{
    "name": "Python: Current File",
    "type": "python",
    "request": "launch",
    "program": "${file}",
    "console": "integratedTerminal"
}]
```

}

Comment: @Sitharth I haven't used vscode api but will definitely look into it and will answer if i get the solution